# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, ads

I was looking for answer for this question (there are a lot of problems coused with this error) but none of them fits me. So I want to call two fragments. If I call only YouTube fragment everything works. On other activitis (with only AdsFragment) everything works fine also.

Here is:

studio.java

```
public class Studio extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_studio);

        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment =
                (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("myapikey", this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
    }



        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                            boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo("film");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
            return (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        }


    public void showPlaylist(View view){

        Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createUserIntent(this, "User");
        startActivity(intent);

}


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
    }
}
```

Here is activity_studio.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    tools:context="pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.Studio"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class = "com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment" />


    <fragment
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentAds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.AdsFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />


    <ImageView
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_studio"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:onClick="showPlaylist"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />


    <TextView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/StudioKrasiniakText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and logcat

```
01-24 22:00:38.394  14282-14282/pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.Studio}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
            at pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.Studio.onCreate(Studio.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.AdsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
            at pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.Studio.onCreate(Studio.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AdsFragment.java

```
public class AdsFragment extends Fragment implements AdListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ads, container, false);

        assert rootView != null;
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_adsLayout);

        AdManager mManager = new AdManager(getActivity(), "url", "code", true);
        mManager.setListener(this);

        AdView mAdView = new AdView(getActivity(), "url",
                "code", true, true);
        mAdView.setAdListener(this);
        layout.addView(mAdView);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void adClicked() {

    }

    @Override
    public void adClosed(Ad ad, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void adLoadSucceeded(Ad ad) {

    }

    @Override
    public void adShown(Ad ad, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void noAdFound() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.AdsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
```

Apparently, your `AdsFragment` either is not a fragment or extends the Android Support package's backport of fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`).

Comment: it's strange becouse on other activitys it works normall... I'm adding AdsFragment.java to my question

Comment: @tuksiarz: Please check your `import` statement for `Fragment`, to see which `Fragment` implementation you have imported.

Comment: I've imported this one `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: @tuksiarz: You need to use a `FragmentActivity` if you want to use the backport of fragments. If your `android:minSdkVersion` is 11 or higher, and you are trying to use the native API Level 11+ version of fragments, you need to import `android.app.Fragment` instead.

Comment: @CommonWare Thank you it work but I don't understand why I had to do this while on diffrent activitys (without any fragments) it was working without problems..

Comment: @CommonsWare i have same problem i have already import android.app.Fragment again i m geting same problem.... can u add more...

Answer (score -2):

I got this error, it was caused by a wrong path on android:class. Please make sure that your code uses a correct path.